# Issue with BackStack method and ViewPager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I have an activity which contains a framelayout. In it, I have a fragment which contains the ViewPager with two different fragments inside. When I push the button in the given fragment, I replace the framelayout container with a new fragment. Now when I press back the ViewPager view is not restored, it's gone.

This is the first fragment:

```
public class CurrencyFragment extends BaseFragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }

    // onclick method for the refresh button on the action bar
    // the method itself calls the anoteher method getCurrency()
    // it also sets visibility to progress bar and loading text and
    // sets invisible to the listview

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:


            Log.i("TAG", "refresh pressed =>");
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    // oncreateView() where the basic view is created

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currency_layout,
                container, false);



        mBankName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Currency_name);
        mBuySell = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Buy_Sell);
        mButtonBuy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Button_buy);
        mButtonSell = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Button_sell);
        mViewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.Detailpager);



        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
        Bank object = (Bank) bundle.getSerializable("message");
        mBankName.setText(object.getName());
        code = object.getCode();
        }

        testadapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),code);
        mViewpager.setAdapter(testadapter);

        if(code.equals("NBG")){
            mBuySell.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             mViewpager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }else{
            mBuySell.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        mViewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position == 0){
                    mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                    mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                }
                else{
                    mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                    mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });





        mButtonBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                mViewpager.setCurrentItem(0);



            }
        });

        mButtonSell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                mViewpager.setCurrentItem(1);


            }
        });

        return view;

    }  

}
```

after is replaced with the other

```
public class DetailedCalculator extends BaseFragment {

    private View detailedView;
    private TextView mButtonBuy;
    private TextView mButtonSell;
    private TextView mDetailedBank;
    private ViewPager mDetailpager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DetailPagerAdapter myAdapter = new DetailPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        detailedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_buy_sell, container, false);
        mButtonBuy = (TextView) detailedView.findViewById(R.id.Detail_buying);
        mButtonSell = (TextView) detailedView.findViewById(R.id.Detail_selling);
        mDetailedBank = (TextView) detailedView.findViewById(R.id.Detail_BankNAme);

        mDetailpager = (ViewPager) detailedView.findViewById(R.id.Detailpager);
        mDetailpager.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        mDetailpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(position == 0){
                    mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                    mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                }
                else{
                    mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                    mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        mButtonBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                mDetailpager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });

        mButtonSell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mButtonSell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2FCEB8"));
                mButtonBuy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                mDetailpager.setCurrentItem(1);

            }
        });


        return detailedView;


    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) instead of `getFragmentManager()` in the fragment containing the `ViewPager` :

```
testadapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),code);
```

To

```
testadapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),code);
```

Comment: very helpful useful and quick solution to the problem :0